# In the binary understood by computers how are positives and negatives and char, int, float, etc distinguished from each other?

Tags: binary, numbers

The binary code used by computers isn't pure Base 2(binary) decimals aren't placed behind a period for computers like they would in base 2, and +/- values don't use the +/- symbols to differentiate between values on either side of 0, so how exactly do computers distinguish them?

Comment: The binary code used by computers is in fact pure Base 2 binary (because if it wasn't it wouldn't be binary). Your understanding of the representation of data is extremely lacking. There's no such thing as a *decimal* in binary, and there isn't in the binary code used by computers. Time for much more research on your part.

Comment: Here - let Google help. [A Tutorial on Data Representation - Integers, Floating Point Numbers, and Characters](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/datarepresentation.html) should get you started on the right path (and answers all of your questions as well).

Comment: I never said that it wasn't binary, just a modified form, hence not pure. Binary does have decimals as does every number system. http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm

Comment: *Binary* does **NOT** have decimals. Decimals can be **represented** in binary. You're misreading what was written in the link you posted. Read the one I provided instead; it's much clearer. If you read it and *still think* that binary has decimals, you need to refresh your understanding of what **0** and **1** are as basic numeric digits.

Comment: Read your own source if you don't believe me Ken, you may want to refresh your understanding of number systems

Comment: I've read it, I've programmed computers for 30+ years, and I understand quite well how data is represented and stored. I'm not the one lacking in knowledge or comprehension here. :-)

Comment: The thing is that computer engineers did not invent binary they chose to BASE how they represented data in a binary FORMAT because of the way transistors work. Number systems are a MATHEMATICAL concept that do in fact have decimals. :-)

Comment: You're more lost than I thought. :-) Computers are electrical in nature; there is either power (on) or no power (off). That's binary. Electricity invented computers, and the fact that power is present or not dictates binary. The thing is you need to learn things at a more elemental nature, and *then* try to understand things more complex. You can't learn to run before you learn you have feet and can stand on them.

Comment: Binary was created by Leibniz, before computers. And the on/off is, just like I said is why engineers chose a binary format for data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with when binary was created. Are  you intentionally being obtuse, or are you just lacking in language comprehension skills? Even according to the link you posted yourself, decimal (and other) numbers have to be **converted to binary** - read the heading. Binary **has no decimals**, and computers deal in **binary**. If you can't understand what the word **convert** means, try dictionary.com. Computers understand **binary**, and all data is represented in **pure binary** internally, whether you want to believe it or not.

Comment: If you have any sort of rudimentary programming skills, write a program that actually saves a decimal (floating point) value in something other than text, and examine the file with a hex editor. You'll find pairs of hex digits (for display), all of which can be converted directly to binary (0 or 1), with nary a decimal point or +/- in sight. Open a text file in a hex editor, and you'll see the same sort of hex digit pairs, all of which can be converted directly to binary without an A, B or c or .,-;? or tab or return in sight. If you plan a career in programming, you really need to get this.

Comment: You try to insult me, but you are to ignorant to understand that the binary that computers use is not the same as the mathematical base 2. When binary was invented does matter genius, because the binary in computers is not the base 2 number system, but a format to handle data that uses Leibniz's base 2 as an inspiration. You act so arrogant but you don't know what you're talking about. To use ANY number system you must convert it. You keep talking in circles, we are talking about two worlds here MATHEMATICS and COMPUTERS. You can't actually dispute my points so you try to insult me, pathetic.

Comment: Um... Did you miss the fact that your question asks about **computers**, and this is a site for **computer programming related questions**, and therefore by definition we are talking about **computer binary**? No need to attempt to insult you; you're doing it all by yourself. No matter. I'm done wasting time here talking to someone who has made up their mind (incorrectly) and refuses to listen. Good luck in your future computer related endeavors - you clearly don't understand the basic premise and are stuck in your point of view no matter how incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The code used by computers is in fact binary, unless you are using a quantum computer :-)

An application may decide how to display numbers to the user in a variety of ways.

Assuming you are using Windows, your computer contains globilization settings for region, language, culture, etc...  These settings will affect the default display for things like dates, times, currency, and numbers.  Other applications may use these settings or implement their own application specific way of displaying data.